# Find all pairs of employees who have the same birthday date each year

Tags: sql

As the title of the question says, I would like to find all pairs of employees who have the same birthday date each year, such as each row of the result table must show a pair of employees and each pair of employees must appear only once in the result table.

My query, as follows, finds only pairs of people with the same birthdate and each pair appears more than once, but not people of differing ages who have the same birthday each year.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E1.empno, 
                E1.firstnme, 
                E1.lastname, 
                E1.birthdate, 
                E2.empno, 
                E2.firstnme, 
                E2.lastname, 
                E2.birthdate 
FROM   employee E1 
       INNER JOIN employee E2 
               ON E1.birthdate = E2.birthdate 
WHERE  Day(E1.birthdate) = Day(E2.birthdate) 
       AND Month(E1.birthdate) = Month(E2.birthdate) 
       AND E1.empno <> E2.empno `
```

I would be very grateful if you can help me!

Comment: how about there are 3 people who have the same birthdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are joining on the actual date.  You can either join on DAY/MONTH or just remove the join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E1.empno, 
                E1.firstnme, 
                E1.lastname, 
                E1.birthdate, 
                E2.empno, 
                E2.firstnme, 
                E2.lastname, 
                E2.birthdate 
FROM   employee E1
INNER JOIN employee E2 
ON Day(E1.birthdate) = Day(E2.birthdate) 
   AND Month(E1.birthdate) = Month(E2.birthdate)
   AND E1.empno < E2.empno
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT E1.empno, 
                E1.firstnme, 
                E1.lastname, 
                E1.birthdate, 
                E2.empno, 
                E2.firstnme, 
                E2.lastname, 
                E2.birthdate 
FROM   employee E1, employee E2 
WHERE  Day(E1.birthdate) = Day(E2.birthdate) 
       AND Month(E1.birthdate) = Month(E2.birthdate) 
       AND E1.empno < E2.empno
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use <> for the empno comparison, use > or <, this will keep the pairs from showing up twice.

```
select e1.*, e2.* 
from employee e1 
inner join employee e2 on month(e2.birthdate)=month(e1.birthdate)
and day(e2.birthdate)=day(e1.birthdate)  and e2.empno > e1.empno
```

Comment: This would only show pairs who have the same birth year, correct?

Comment: I edited the query to ignore the year part of the dates.

Comment: @JoeLove you are ignoring the day, not the year.

Comment: I apologize, please look again. My brain was broken apparently. Thanks for the heads up @DStanley

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!

put the where conditions in the join and you are done.

```
FROM   employee E1 
   INNER JOIN employee E2 
           ON Day(E1.birthdate) = Day(E2.birthdate) 
              AND Month(E1.birthdate) = Month(E2.birthdate) 
              AND E1.empno <> E2.empno `
```